# What are the common tennis terms in Italian?

Tags: vocabulary, nouns

Particularly for

- [advantage set / tiebreaker set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_scoring_system#Scoring_a_tiebreak_game)
- game
- set
- match
- love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation)
- 15/30/40
- deuce
- advantage in / advantage out

Answer (score 6):

- set di vantaggio / set tiebreak
- partita
- set
- gioco
- love (same)
- quindici/trenta/quaranta
- pari (but "deuce" is used as well)
- vantaggio (used for both in and out)

More:

- racchetta (racket)
- campo (field)
- fuori (when the ball goes out)
- arbitro (referee)
- lungolinea (down the line shot)
- ace (same as English)
- fallo (fault)
- vittoria (victory)
- sconfitta (defeat)

I used to play tennis but I can only think of these words at the moment. Most English words are used in Italian too.

Comment: I'm uncertain about *partita* for *match*, as I remember it used for *set*: *gioco, partita, incontro* is/was used for announcing the winner, where English has *game, set and match*.

Comment: yeah egreg is right, I mixed the two terms. Sorry!

Comment: @Charo: fatto! scusate il ritardo

Comment: Ora però “gioco” sembra corrispondere a “match” e “partita” a “game”. A me sembrava che “partita” dovesse corrispondere a “set”.

Comment: Game, set, match in italiano sono Gioco, Partita, Incontro.

Comment: ["Game" = "Gioco", "Set" = "Partita" (but in older times, now it's "set" in Italian too), "Match" = "Incontro"](http://www.tennisworlditalia.com/news/news/Lezioni_Tennis/37148/game-set-match-o-gioco-partita-incontro-se-preferite/), "Deuce" = "Parità", "Advantage in" = "Vantaggio interno", "Advantage out" = "Vantaggio esterno". See also https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091111065718AA72RS7 . @genespos answer is correct.

Comment: I termini giusti li mette @genespos

Answer (score 2):

Le corrispondenze sono le seguenti:
•advantage set / tiebreaker set
TIEBREAK.

•game. 
GIOCO.

•set. 
PARTITA.

•match. 
INCONTRO.

•love (the term used for 0 or a no score situation). 
- questa non l'ho mai sentita in italiano-

•15/30/40. 
-identici con pronuncia italiana.

•deuce. 
PARITÀ

•advantage in / advantage out. 
VANTAGGIO INTERNO/VANTAGGIO ESTERNO

Comment: si dice 0 per love (15 a 0, per esempio)